# How to re-install syslinux on a re-formatted (fat32 to fat16) partition

Tags: debian, usb-drive, live-usb, syslinux

I wrote an `.img` file containing a custom debian distro to a USB stick via win32diskimager program. The stick doesn't boot on my older motherboard, returning:

> SYSLINUX: No DEFAULT or UI configuration directive found

I learned that it's because my motherboard doesn't recognize FAT32 partitions. It will only boot from a FAT16 partition. Sadly win32diskimager creates a FAT32 partition by default and there are no means to configure it.

[image: usb stick after writing .img by win32diskimager]
[image: usb stick fat32 partition content]

I found a workaround by someone who wrote:

> I've managed to recreate with fat16 filesystem, by reformatting the
>   525MB partition, copying over the files and reinstalling syslinux
>   (latest version, 4.05) - and now it boots. It looks like indeed some
>   motherboards have issues booting from fat32 USB sticks.

I have followed the workaround and done this:

- Made a copy of all the contents of the fat32 partition
- Unmounted and formatted the fat32 partition to fat16 via gparted (at this point the new fat16 partition is not marked as boot in the flags column)
- Copied the contents back to the newly created fat16 partition

Unfortunately I do not know how to reinstall syslinux on the USB stick so that it boots. I've got syslinux available (`syslinux --version` => `4.05`) from the command line but have no idea what to do with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Check that you USB fat16 partition is still /dev/sdb1.
- Open a terminal window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>).
- Execute this command:

  `$ sudo syslinux --directory /syslinux/ --install /dev/sdb1`